# How can I real time check for exceptions after JTextField has been entered

Tags: java, exception

Say I have a input field which will only accept a `Int` when the submit button is pressed.

How can I say disable the button should the field check not be a `int`.

Ignore the `Add Number` button it's irrelevant.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sure there must be some sort of onkeypress event that you can capture and check that the input is valid.

Comment: Ah thats a good point I'll look into it thank you.

Comment: Lots of ways.  Write some ad-hoc code.  Use an [InputVerifier.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html).  Use a DocumentFilter.  Make your own custom Document. Etc.

Comment: You can use `JFormattedTextField`

Comment: Check here: (JFormattedTextField) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Comment: I've read that JFormattedTextField is not good to use some call it evil?

Comment: No, it's probably your best bet for this particular problem.  I'd call trying to sniff the key events evil.  Don't ever do that, it's a huge mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you **Could** use `DocumentListener` like this :

```
    Document document = jTextFiled.getDocument();
    document.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            check();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            check();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            check();
        }

        private void check() {
            if (!isInteger(jTextFiled.getText())) {
                jButton.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                jButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: He "could", not should.  The JFormattedTextField that was already mentioned is probably a much better idea.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) is the best way to do this.  You'll need to customize the formatter's `valueToString` method, since NumberFormat normally ignores trailing characters:

```
final JButton acceptButton = new JButton("Add Volume");
acceptButton.setEnabled(false);

NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();

NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format) {
    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text)
    throws ParseException {
        ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
        Object value = getFormat().parseObject(text, pos);
        if (value != null && pos.getIndex() >= text.length()) {
            return value;
        }
        throw new ParseException(text, pos.getErrorIndex());
    }
};
formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);
formatter.setAllowsInvalid(true);

JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
field.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT);

field.addPropertyChangeListener("editValid",
    new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            boolean valid = (Boolean) event.getNewValue();
            acceptButton.setEnabled(valid);
        }
    });
```